# Charles can't see HTTP requests with VPN opened on android

Tags: android, request, response, vpn, charles-proxy

Im using OpenVPN on my Android device and have to catch HTTP requests.

- charles-proxy-ssl-proxying-certificate is installed
- wi fi proxy is correct

but still while VPN is working - no requests - if VPN is turned off I can catch everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is simple - just add proxy address and port to your VPN connection. (explm. if you using Open VPN connector > go to settings (MORE) > Add Proxy > Select createt proxy > Press Connect

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue than I realize the IP address of Charles and the proxy settings of my emulator are different. Therefore follow these steps;

- Go to Charles: Help -> Local Ip address and copy it
- Go Emulator Settings then click Proxy and enter Charles Ip address here.

Comment: Your solution doesn't depend on VPN.